# What will be a better option: parse XML directly or convert XML to JSON and then do the parsing?

Tags: php, json, xml, performance, simplexml

I have `XML` as a string and I need to parse it and then store the values in database. I have two ways:

- Parse XML using [simple xml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)
- Convert the XML string to JSON (I will use IBM's [x-xml2jsonphp](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml2jsonphp/))

What will better approach in terms of efficiency and maintainability and why?

Comment: From my experience, working with SimpleXML is really dreadful. Technically  it should be faster to parse xml directly than converting it to json (because you have to parse it all first before you convert it to json - in this case, library does it for you). Recently for parsing XML and HTML I've been using [symfony/dom-crawler](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler) with [symfony/css-selector](https://github.com/symfony/css-selector) and it works really well. Code looks really clean as well.

Comment: @Skysplit Could you please elaborate, how was working with SimpleXML dreadful?

Comment: What I find really stupid (just personal opinion) that you have to call `$node->__toString()` or `(string) $node` to get inner html of given node. I'm also not a huge fan of XPath. Symfony's dom-crawler gives you some more fluent API (filtering using CSS selectors is also very convenient feature for me).

Comment: @Skysplit I'm not sure how you could avoid calling some method to get the string content out of an object. I've not used Symfony's DomCrawler, but at a glance, it appears you have to call `->text()`, which seems basically the same thing?

Comment: @IMSoP yes, I have to call this method. But calling `$node->text()` looks way much nicer than `$node->__toString()` or `(string) $node`. Again, It's just my personal opinion. If you're comfortable with SimpleXML, then feel free to use it. It works really well after all :)

Comment: @Skysplit You could always write `class MySimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement { public function text() { return (string)$this; } }` then `$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'MySimpleXMLElement');` :) [And yeah, `__toString` looks really ugly, but I'd never use it that way.] CSS-style selectors can be handy though, particularly if you're not familiar with XPath, or need something not available in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Converting XML to JSON and then processing the JSON is almost bound to be slower, because you are parsing, serializing, and then re-parsing, which is bound to take longer than just parsing.

Whether it's simpler and more maintainable depends entirely on the XML. If it's using features like namespaces and mixed content then conversion to JSON will usually either (a) give you very complicated JSON to deal with, or (b) lose information that your application might need. (But I don't know the particular library you are proposing to use). On the other hand, if it's very simple XML, then you might need to write less code this way, and that equates to better maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Converting XML to JSON requires you to either discard some of the structure of the XML, or have a very deeply nested set of JSON objects and arrays. In the first case, you're throwing away information which you might want later; in the second, you're creating something harder to work with than the XML was in the first place.

Either way, once you've converted to JSON, you'll then have to parse that JSON in order to actually use it, just as you'd have to parse the XML each time, so there's no real difference there that I can think of.

If you're using PHP, SimpleXML is (in my opinion) a pretty neat tool. It's important to remember that it's *not just a big nested* array containing the XML, it's *an API for accessing data*. So for instance, you don't have to worry about whether there is a single `<foo>` child or several, `foreach ( $node->foo as $foo )` will always work, and `echo $node->foo` will always be equivalent to `echo $node->foo[0]`.

Or, as mentioned in comments, there are other XML APIs out there, which might better fit your needs. With JSON, though, you're pretty much stuck with `json_decode`, and then dealing with a massive array of data (once you've parsed it, it's not JSON any mor); although you might be able to find helper functions for going deep into PHP arrays somewhere.